# How to ignore broadcast package in libpcap program?

Tags: filter, expression, broadcast, pcap, libpcap

I am working on the monitor network program using libpcap. I have searched but fail to find the good way to ignore the broadcast packages filter expression so that I set it to kernel.

Could you please give me the advice or the sample of code for that?

Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 0):

The filter expression to ignore broadcast packets is "not broadcast".